# Configuring NetBeans 7.3 JPQL editor?

Tags: netbeans, jpql

I have a RESTful service that builds and runs fine. However, when I try to use the JPQL editor, it gives the error:

```
java.lang.Exception: You need to add your persistence provider library either to project classpath or registed as Ant Library within Netbeans
You need to register database connection on Services tab
```

I'm using EclipseLink 2.4.1 as my persistence library, and I already have a library added in the Ant manager as `"EclipseLink 2.4."` When that failed, I made a library called `"EclipseLink (JPA 2.0)(default)`" to match the persistence.xml GUI name for it. I even tried creating a library named "org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider. All failed and now I'm stumped.

I have a connection the SQL Server database I'm using and it works fine.

I really am unsure of what I need to do to get this working. The editor seems like it would be a great boon, but there doesn't seem to be much documentation on it, nor questions with problems similar to mine. If anybody can help, that would be great.